# многопоточный socket сервер python

Tags: python, многопоточность, сокет

Сервер:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('192.168.0.100', 1080))
sock.listen(3)
conn = []

def Reciver():
    while 1:
        for i in range(len(conn)):
            try:
                data = conn[i].recv(1024)
                if data:
                    print(data.decode())
            except socket.error as e:
                if e.errno == 10053:
                    conn.pop(i)
                    print("Подключено пользователй:", len(conn))
                else:
                    raise

def Sender():
    while 1:
        global conn
        message = input()
        if message:
            for i in range(len(conn)):
                conn[i].send(message.encode())

def Accepter():
    while 1:
        global conn
        conn.append(sock.accept()[0])
        print("Подключено пользователй:", len(conn))


# init threads
t1 = threading.Thread(target=Reciver)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=Sender)
t3 = threading.Thread(target=Accepter)

# start threads
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

Код клиента:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys

host = "192.168.0.100"
port = 1080
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((host, port))

def Reciver():
    while 1:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        if data:
            print(data.decode())

def Sender():
    while 1:
        message = input()
        if message == "exit":
            sock.close()
            sys.exit()
        else:
            sock.send(message.encode())

# init threads
t1 = threading.Thread(target=Reciver)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=Sender)

# start threads
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Проблемы: При подключении 2 клиентов получается что нормально писать может только сервер, а от клиентов приходят багнутые сообщения. А еще при отключении клиентов, сервер долго это понимает из-за чего при отключении 2 сразу происходит баг и отключается только 1, и выдается ошибка, после которой не работает отправка сообщений ни на сервере ни на клиенте..

Comment: В Интернете так же полно инструкций по многопоточности. Если вы действительно поймёте инструкции по обеим темам, то для вас не составит труда их объединить.

Comment: Можете объяснить как принимать все входящие соединения и потом посылать сообщения сразу всем подключенным?

Comment: Добавлять каждое новое подключение в список. Потом обходить список в цикле и отправлять сообщение в каждый сокет.

Comment: Код добавил. Почему мне ошибку кидает, и как удалять при отключении из списка?

Comment: Добавьте ещё полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Добавил ошибку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[socket.accept()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) возвращает кортеж из сокета и адреса. Поэтому вам надо либо код `conn.append(sock.accept())` поменять на `conn.append(sock.accept()[0])`, либо код `conn[i].send(message.encode())` на `conn[i][0].send(message.encode())`.

У вас в коде есть ещё немало мест, которые стоило бы изменить, но конкретно к этой ошибке они не относятся.

**UPDATE:**

```
try:
    conn[i].send(message.encode())
except socket.error as e:
    if e.errno == errno.ECONNRESET:
        # Сокет закрыт
        # обрабатываем этот факт каким-либо образом
    else:
        # Какая-то другая ошибка
        # пробрасываем её дальше
        raise
```

Comment: Хорошо, сообщения с сервера клиенту доходят, теперь осталось вот что сделать: Удалять из списка при отключении и наладить отправку с клиента к серверу сообщения, я попробую наладить отправку с клиента,а вы расскажите как понять что человек отключился)

Comment: Отправка клиент - сервер починил)

Comment: Правильный вариант - отправка клиентом сообщения об отключении. Проверяйте его так же, как сообщение `exit` проверяете. А вот нештатное отключение можно обнаружить только попытавшись прочитать из закрытого сокета и нарвавшись на ошибку. Самый простой способ - завернуть операции чтения\записи в `try-catch` и в обработчике `socket.error` удалять сбойные сокеты.

Comment: А как это реализовать? Можно пример хотя бы?

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Только не пытайтесь удалить сокет из списка, который обходите в цикле. Это само по себе может привести к приключениям, а в многопоточной среде - это натурально _выстрел в ногу™_.

Comment: Лучше будет проверять при получении данных. Я тут выявил баги новые, если подключается мой друг и я, то получается так что сервер может писать обоим сразу, а вот серверу писать может только тот кто 1 подключился, то есть друг подключился первее и мои сообщения до сервера не доходят. А так же сервер ругается на if e.errno == errno.ECONNRESET, а точнее на errno после ==

Comment: А нет. сообщения отправляет тот кто последний подключается [ссылка](http://imgur.com/a/gV7nZ)

Comment: Сделал удаление правильное, но что-то не пойму, если 2 чел подключаются, то пишет только 1, а как я понял через несколько попыток, что сообщения 2 доходят но каким-то странным образом. Сделал [скрин](http://imgur.com/a/2fJl4)

Comment: Обновил код. Посмотри пожалуйста. Вообще не понимаю почему не приходят сообщения от 2 клиента, а после сообщения 1 клиента доходит сообщение 2 клиента

Comment: Я могу полностью переписать ваш код, так как надо. Могу сразу ссылку дать на рабочий код. Но это не поможет вам разобраться. Пытайтесь. Когда упрётесь в проблему, которую не сможете решить за двое суток, например, тогда пишите новый вопрос.

Comment: Хех я эту программу уже пишу 3 день) Ну ладно, напишу если не выйдет через 2 дня. Спасибо что помогли с отключениями, я только код подправил чтобы он работал)

Comment: Я не могу понять, почему этот кусок кода не работает? try: conn[i].send(message.encode())  Просто выходит ошибка и поток останавливается, try же должен ошибку увидеть и пройти по expect, почему не срабатывает?

Comment: Какая ошибка выходит?

Comment: ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение. А должно просто пройти по expect и удалить юзера из списка.

Comment: Добавьте обработчик для `ConnectionAbortedError`.

Comment: У меня стоит if e.errno == 10053: Код ошибки именно такой

Comment: А исключение, видимо, не такое. Мы уже основательно превысили рекомендуемую длину переписки. Скоро придут модераторы и наругают нас.

Comment: Может чат? Я сидел час и сильно не сдвинулся с места

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60982/discussion-between-mr-lucky-tomas-and-sergey-gornostaev).